# What should I call the disposable paper wrappers for straws?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Just for personal reasons I would like to know what to call the disposable paper wrappers for drinking straws. If there is no name can I name it a paper? Paper wrapper?

Comment: Maybe *strapper*?

Comment: Strawphylactic. Or just condom.

Comment: We've always just called it a "*straw paper*"

Comment: I've heard it called a "straw wrapper".

Comment: If you really appreciate how great straws are, you could call it "gift wrap".

Comment: Yes, straws have paper wrappers or just wrapper for short.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, there is no special term, in industry or otherwise, for the protective covering of an individually wrapped drinking straw.

It could be called a *sleeve*, in [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sleeve)'s second sense, especially if made of paper:

> 2. a paper or plastic cover that protects something such as a record or a book

I think most people, however, would simply refer to it as the *[wrapper](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wrapper)* or (*[wrapping](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wrapping)*).

> a piece of paper, plastic etc that is wrapped around something that you buy

No one I know would refer to it as *a paper*, but I would expect people who are familiar with such straws to understand if you referred to the material— *I peeled the [paper](http://www.strawsking.com/our-products/drinking-straw-wrapping-paper/) from the straw* or *I removed the straw from its [shrink wrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrink_wrap).*

Comment: Yes, it's a sleeve.

Comment: No, it's a wrapper because it is completely sealed.  A sleeve normally remains open.

Comment: Google images supports the term *wrapper*. Here's a [link](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=straw+wrapper&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji4cOi8qbUAhUEHZQKHSIZD3sQsAQIIg&biw=1920&bih=925) for your convenience.